# Looking for references for a hadith about Jews and Muslims

Tags: hadith

I have heard many times from various people a famous hadith attributed to the prophet that says something like:

> there is no pitfall that Jews fall in and Muslims will not fall in

I tried to find a reference for it by searching on the internet but wasn't successful.

Can someone tell me the exact wording and give a reference where I can find it? 
How [authentic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadith_terminology) is this hadtih? Is it considered sahih or mutawatir?

I am looking for both Sunni and Shia references and viewpoints regarding this hadith.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am only familiar with the Sunni sources. Is this the hadith you're looking for?

> Abu Sa'id al-Khudri reported Allah's Messenger (may peace be upon him) as saying:
>   You would tread the same path as was trodden by those before you inch by inch and step by step so much so that if they had entered into the hole of the lizard, you would follow them in this also. We said: Allah's Messenger, do you mean Jews and Christians (by your words)" those before you"? He said: Who else (than those two religious groups)?

From http://sunnah.com/muslim/48#7

Comment: This is not exactly the same as what I have heard but the meaning is very similar so I might have heard another variation of it. Thanks.